# Compare row and previous row upon change in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, compare

I have longitudinal data of the following form

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': ['apples', 'plums', 'pears', 'pears', 'pears'],
    'b': ['grapes', 'grapes', 'grapes', 'grapes', 'bananas'],
    'c': [0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
})
```

and a function which compares lists (the details of this aren't important)

```
def compare(old_fruit, new_fruit):
    if set(new_fruit) - set(old_fruit) == {'pears'}:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
```

`c` is 1 when a change occurs in `a` and `b` that I am interested in. I want to find the rows where `c` = 1, grab the values of `a` and `b` at that point, plus the values of `a` and `b` from the previous row, compare them using my function and add a new Series to the dataframe showing the result of the comparison.

For the example above, my desired operation would execute `compare(['plums', 'grapes'], ['pears', 'grapes'])` and `compare(['pears', 'grapes'], ['pears', 'bananas'])` and add the Series `[0, 0, 1, 0, 0]` to the dataframe, i.e. the desired output is a dataframe as follows:

```
pd.DataFrame({
    'a': ['apples', 'plums', 'pears', 'pears', 'pears'],
    'b': ['grapes', 'grapes', 'grapes', 'grapes', 'bananas'],
    'c': [0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
    'd': [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
})
```

Comment: Please add a running example and the desired output.

Comment: Hi. The desired output is an array of zeros and ones the same length as the dataframe, `[0, 0, 1, 0, 0]` in this case, which is 1 where the compare function is executed and returns 1 and is 0 otherwise. My `compare()` function returns 1 and 0 respectively for the two examples given. I don't know how to write a running example for the rest unfortunately.

Comment: I mean code which can be copy pasted from your question, so I can run it on my pc (with dummy data, imports and desired output as comment).

Comment: I've added the import statement and the desired output. `df` is the dummy data. Please let me know if I am missing something else.

Comment: You're almost there :) I'd like one block I can copy in my IDE and simple run it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do exactly what you want to compare in a vectorized way:

```
df_set = df[['a', 'b']].apply(set, axis=1)

df_set
Out[38]: 
0    {grapes, apples}
1     {grapes, plums}
2     {grapes, pears}
3     {grapes, pears}
4    {bananas, pears}
dtype: object

(df_set - df_set.shift()) == {'pears'}
Out[39]: 
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
4    False
dtype: bool
```